# How to do a negative lookbehind within a %r<…>-delimited regexp in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, syntax, syntax-error, regex-lookarounds

I like the `%r<…>` delimiters because it makes it really easy to spot the beginning and end of the regex, and I don't have to escape any `/`. But it seems that they have an insurmountable limitation that other delimiters don't have?

Every other delimiter imaginable works fine:

```
/(?<!foo)/
%r{(?<!foo)}
%r[(?<!foo)]
%r|(?<!foo)|
%r/(?<!foo)/
```

But when I try to do this:

```
%r<(?<!foo)>
```

it gives this syntax error:

```
unterminated regexp meets end of file
```

Okay, it probably doesn't like that it's not a balanced pair, but how do you escape it such that it *does* like it?

**Does something need to be escaped?**

According to [wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_%25_Notation):

> Any single non-alpha-numeric character can be used as the delimiter,
>   `%[including these], %?or these?, %~or even these things~`.
>   By using this notation, the usual string delimiters " and ' can appear
>   in the string unescaped, but of course the new delimiter you've chosen
>   does need to be escaped.

Indeed, escaping is needed in these examples:

```
%r!(?<\!foo)!                                                             
%r?(\?<!foo)?
```

But if that were the only problem, then I should be able to escape it like this and have it work:

```
%r<(?\<!foo)>
```

But that yields this error:

```
undefined group option: /(?\<!foo)/
```

So maybe escaping is *not* needed/allowed? [wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_%25_Notation) does list `%<pointy brackets>` as one of the exceptions:

> However, if you use
>   `%(parentheses), %[square brackets], %{curly brackets}` or
>   `%<pointy brackets>` as delimiters then those same delimiters
>   can appear *unescaped* in the string as long as they are in *balanced*
>   pairs

**Is it a problem with *balanced* pairs?**

Balanced pairs are no problem as long as you are doing something in the Regexp that requires them, like...

```
%r{(?<!foo{1})}   # repetition quantifier
%r[(?<![foo])]    # character class
%r<(?<name>foo)>  # named capture group
```

But what if you need to insert a left-side delimiter ({, [, or <) inside the regex? Just escape it, right? Ruby seems to have no problem with escaped unbalanced delimiters *most* of the time...

```
%r{(?<!foo\{)}                                                                  
%r[(?<!\[foo)]
%r<\<foo>
```

It's just when you try to do it in the middle of the "group options" (which I guess is what the `<!` characters are classified as here) following a `(?` that it doesn't like it:

```
%r<(?\<!foo)>
# undefined group option: /(?\<!foo)/
```

So how do you do that then and make Ruby happy? (without changing the delimiters)

**Conclusion**

The workaround is easy. I'll just change this particular regex to just use something else instead like `%r{…}` instead.

But the questions remain...

1. Is there really no way to escape the `<` here?
2. Are there really some regular expression that are simply impossible to write using certain delimiters like `%r<…>`?
3. Is `%r<…>` the only regular expression delimiter pair that has this problem (where some regular expressions are impossible to write when using it). If you know of a similar example with `%r{…}`/`%r[…]`, do share!

**Version info**

Not that it probably matters since this syntax probably hasn't changed, but I'm using:

```
⟫ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux]
```

Reference:

- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html
- [% Notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_%25_Notation)

Comment: What do you get with `%r<(?<=<)>` the unbalance ? Is `%r` raw string notation ?

Comment: Theorehticallly, the cure for the special pairs, is to use a single delimiter. As, it needs balanced pairs (unescaped) to determine where the closing delimiter is. Otherwise its `.*>` which takes you way past there. Since, there is no magic parsing going on here.

Comment: And, if you think about it, only the _pointy_ ones are used _un-paired_ in regex construct's. All  the other pairs are balanced. I'd steer clear of that pair `<>`

Comment: @sin Aren't <> _usually_ paired as well, like `/(?<name>foo)/`? Even the other pairs need to be able to be used unpaired at times, such as within character classes: `/^[{fo]+$/.match?('foo{')`. The difference seems to be that in all other cases, you _can_ simply escape the unbalanced delimiter, like: `%r{[\{fo]}`. Whereas, for some reason, in the case of a < within the group options, you don't even have the ability/option to (you _can't_) do that.

Comment: `/^[{fo]+$/` no pairing going on here. Anything used as a construct identifier `(?here)` cant be escaped in a raw string for the sake of it being a delimiter. That is the only restriction. The lookarounds `(?<=)`, `(?<!)` seem to be the culprit of this behavior.

Comment: Even if it were `{^[\{fo]+$}` it could safely be escaped in a class.

Comment: Construct identifier's are part of a rigid parsing process done by engines.

Comment: > Construct identifier's are part of a rigid parsing process done by engines

< I guess that's what it comes down to. Group options like `<=` and `<!` are just parsed in a very rigid way that doesn't permit escaping? Feel free to submit something like that as an answer. (I wish Stackoverflow permitted Markdown in comments, so you could do quotes/replies properly.)

Comment: Good advice regarding using a single (non-pair) delimiter. Doesn't quite satisfy my desire to have an easy-to-spot beginning and end character, but you're right that we would avoid the problem of balanced pairs if we did that! :) Didn't fully understand some of your other technical comments without asking for clarifications, but that's okay...

Comment: I would steer toward using delimiter characters that are seldom seen in regex, yet visible to the naked eye. The tilde `~` is a good choice.

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you're asking about `%r<(?<=<)>` now. Wait, don't you mean `%r<(?<=>)>`? Yes, that actually works! Proving that it really is simply a matter of requiring balanced pairs. Except that it's not always possible, 'cause I don't really _want_ my group to match a  a `>` :)

Comment: Nice, I'll give `~` a try!

Comment: Too bad the parser seems to only allow ASCII characters following `%r`. Because `%r❮❯` would make a _great_ pair of delimiters, since you'd pretty much never need to use it inside the regex! Come on, Ruby, let us use Unicode as delimiters! To its credit though, it does let us use Unicode in method/variable names: `def ❮❯_are_good_delimiters?; true; end; ❮❯_are_good_delimiters?`  (Here's a whole list of matching bracket characters: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_matching_brackets.html)

Comment: `%`, `!`, and `#` look like some other good delimiter options I might try. Nice and visible to the eye but not often used inside of regexes (depending on your domain area, of course)...

Comment: @TylerRick what is your objection to a single pipe `|` while they are often used inside regex they do not require termination either and I think that `%r|(?<=foo)|` brackets the expression much better than `%r~(?<=foo)~` especially in say `str =~ %r~(?<=foo)~` that is a lot of tildas

Comment: Rarely does one encounter a question that is interesting, challenging and extremely well-presented. Good job!

Comment: Thanks, Cary! :)

Comment: @engineersmnky, I have no objections to a pipe symbol `|` as delimiter... except, as you alluded to, they are used inside regexes a more often (I would guess) than the other options presented. Great examples! It does bracket the expression better in those examples. Maybe `|` is a good one to start with, and I could change it to `!` (which is rather similar visually) if need to use any `|`s inside the regex. Still figuring out what I like the best... :)

Comment: Expecting `<>` to be balanced in the regexp is not reasonable. I'd say file a bug against Ruby so they fix this. Same goes for `()` etc. although I can see why they thought these would only occur balanced, but it's not a safe assumption (consider for eg. `%r([)])`)

Comment: Bravo, this was a *beautifully* found edge case of ruby/regexp parsing. Personally I use `%r(...)` as I find it reads like "group 0" of MatchData: $~[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, seems like an oversight based on how this character differs from other paired boundaries.

As far as "Is there really no way to escape the < here?" there is a way... but you're not going to like it:

```
%r<(?#{'<'}!foo)> == %r((?<!foo))
```

Using interpolation to insert the `<` character seems to work. But given that there are much better options, I would avoid it unless you were planning on splitting the regex into sections anyway...